# Generate sonar-reports on a ruby project using gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab, sonarqube, rubygems, sonarscanner

I have a ruby project setup on gitlab and I need to generate sonar coverage for it. There is no way to setup sonar-scanner other than using gemfile. How can I achieve that? Also, do I have to generate the reports using bundle exec sonar-scanner command or is there any other way?

Comment: Not sure what gem you're talking about. There are [no ruby projects](https://github.com/SonarSource?q=&type=&language=ruby) in sonarsource repo where I could say they're maintaining a gem. Looking for sonar gems, [there's a bunch](https://rubygems.org/search?query=sonar), so it'll help if you say what gem you're using. I've never used this code analyzer, but it looks has more to do [with the config in gitlab](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/gitlab-integration/) than the project itself, but I might be wrong, so please share more details about what's your issue.

Comment: Mainly I want to run sonar scanner to send my coverage and other reports to my sonar project. I have no way to install sonar scanner on the machine that I am running the code on. So I wanted to understand how to configure it using gemfile.